# Stop bath squeaking

Tags: bathtub, squeak

I have a bath as shown in the attached images.

It squeaks a lot.

The bath sits on a chipboard floor as shown.

The vertical gap between the chipboard floor and the suspended bath is 14cm.

I tightened the bolts underneath some time ago and this stopped the squeaking for a while.

Taking the bath out is not the preferred option : in-situ remedy if possible is preferred.

The options appear to be

o expanding foam, though I'm not sure how to approach this.

o Cement underneath, build this up, though I'm not sure how to approach this.

All advice in how to approach this appreciated

:)

[image: The bath]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest a shower radio.

Answer (score 1):

You should determine where the squeak is originating before doing anything messy/drastic, since it might not fix the problem.

I would guess that the squeak originates where the tubing touches the chipboard on the bottom of the tub.  Would it be possible to unscrew (loosen) the tube from the chipboard and put cardboard on the top of the tube, then test for a squeak?

Do the tubes touch the side of the tub?  If so, wedge in a bit of cardboard from a cereal box to test if that is the source of the squeak.

If either of those result in non-squeakyness, then you can look at doing something more durable, such as separate the tube from the chipboard by 1/16", and squirting in silicone, or put some cloth, electrical or hockey tape between the two.  Squeaks usually originate where two hard surfaces meet, and they stick together and build up stress.  When they release they produce a tick, like you might hear with pipes warming/cooling in walls, or if the ticking happens rapidly enough it's a squeak.

Answer (score 0):

That is a somewhat different arrangement than we usually see.

Don't use cement - use plaster - it's much easier to remove when the the time comes, while being perfectly stable until then.

You might try some threadlocking compound on the bolts as a first approach.

For either foam or plaster fill with this arrangement, you'll want to block off the drain pipe area (and probably the far end of the tub as well) to simplify the future.

Polyurethane Foam is both easy, and tricky - it expands after you apply it, so if you put in what looks like enough, it may become too much. Safest to plug the tub and run it half-full of water for ballast - if using the typical cans of foam, squirt one all around on the floor and wait for it to expand and cure before adding more - that will give you an idea of how much it expands. This is a fairly high off the floor installation, so you'll certainly need more than one can (or you could **fill some space with a sheet of rigid insulating foam** - styrofoam - and then add spray foam on top.)

For plaster, you just mix it up and stuff it in to fill the gap between the floor and the bottom of the tub. On a new tub install the recommended method is to put a pile of it on the floor and set the tub into it. As above, you could take some of the vast space you have on this install out with a sheet of rigid foam.

**Given the height, I'm going to strongly suggest the rigid foam sheet as part of your solution, it will make for a much faster, neater fix.**

Comment: It is obvious that the metal in the picture isn't strong enough to hold a tub, grown man, and water. It is flexing - partly due to its adjustable design.  I would reinforce or change out the metal before putting anything under.

Comment: Once properly bedded on plaster or foam, there's no weight to speak of carried by the metal, as it will pass directly to the floor. And it obviously **is** strong enough carry the weight mentioned since it has been in use for some time and is not collapsed, or even bent - merely squeaky.

Comment: I just think the plaster is overkill and could in itself have "rubbing" issues with tub.  The supports are strong enough to keep it up but not strong enough to not flex when in use.  I think just some rubber gaskets is a good start.

Comment: plaster is a standard tub support material - there's no "rubbing" - it simply removes the opportunity for the tub base to flex under load. Just don't stand in or fill the tub until it has set. While it is often left as optional, it's generally recommended. i.e. *"Casting plaster/plaster of paris (herein referred as foundation materials) are not necessary but its use is highly recommended for a firmer bottom support."* from http://aquaticbath.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Bathtubs-LITID1901-Doc-1901-04.22.14.pdf

Comment: Not saying plastering shouldn't be used for tubs, but his tub is open and I have never seen plaster just sitting under open tub.  Not sure this is the type you would do that to since those kinds of tubs have sides that hold the weight or at least disperse the weight outward better.  I see plaster working short term but then splitting and falling out after a while.

Comment: There is a skirt which has been removed for pictures of the support structure. You can see part of it on the end in the first picture. The plaster is not, and does not need to be "held in" on any tub install - it simply sits in a pile under the bottom of the tub, and sets there as a solid mass. Until you remove the tub and take a hammer to it, it's not going anywhere.